# Get a random element from a hash in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hash, hashmap, hashtable, associative-array

I have a hash table in JavaScript:

```
a['b'] = 'c';
a['d'] = 'e';
```

I know I can get the length of my hash with `a.length`. How do I get a random element within the hash? I don't know how or if it's possible to index it like an array.

I know I can create a separate array of the hash keys, but I'd like to make this far easier and only deal with the 1 hash.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no such notion in JavaScript as hash table or associative array. In JS this thing is called *object*. And looking at your sintax `a['b']='c'` I can conclude that `a` is an object (and, by the way, objects does not have 'magic' `length` property, like arrays do).

You can get array of keys (property names) from object `a` as simple as `Object.keys(a)`, so complete solution will be like this

```
function randomValueOf( obj ) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    var len = keys.length;
    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*len);
    var key = keys[rnd];
    return obj[key];
}
```

Comment: getting all the keys from an object toget a random is far from efficent.

Comment: @user2445942 Yes, it does not seem to be O(1) efficient (but actually can be, if internal implementation of Object.keys is clever enough - not straightforward copy-based). In spite of this, I think it is just optimal - the best solution possible for the language and task presented. Because there is no way to address object member by its number, or somehow guess a correct string from the set of object keys in general case (without refering to the same Object.keys)

Comment: @user2445942 Another possible method is to loop for(in) a random number of times, between 1 and number of keys in the object, but it is equivalent O(N) solution.